# tornado websocket compression options

Tags: websocket, tornado

There is currently a function in tornado:

```
WebSocketHandler.get_compression_options()
```

Is there a current leading compression method people are using for websockets at the moment? Would Tornado look to adopt these compression methods in the future? How would the clients decompress the received message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado supports websocket compression according to [RFC 7692](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692). To enable compression, return an empty dictionary from [`get_compression_options()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.get_compression_options) (instead of `None`, which is the default and disables compression). If compression is enabled on both sides of the connection it will be used automatically; this is transparent to the application.

In the future, it may be possible to return other options in this dictionary (such as a `compression_level` parameter) to make tradeoffs between the amount of compression and CPU/memory usage, although no such options are currently implemented.

Comment: Thanks Ben, what determines if the client has compression enabled? Do I need to set something in the HTTP headers? Or do something for the client to put compression on? I can't imagine that a low level option like this would be available for configuration in a browser?

Comment: If the client is also tornado, the websocket_connect function takes a compression_options argument. I don't know about other clients

Answer (score 0):

Compression supported in 4.0

[WebSocketHandler.get_compression_options()](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.get_compression_options)

example code :

```
class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def get_compression_options(self):
        # Non-None enables compression with default options.
        return {'compression_level':5,'mem_level':5}
```